# Problematic output of fmod (long double, long double)

Tags: c++, g++, fmod

Problematic output of fmod (long double, long double)

It seems that output of fmod (long double, long double) in this test is problematocs.
Any suggestions?

> g++ --version
>   g++ (GCC) 4.9.2
>
> uname -srvmpio
>   CYGWIN_NT-6.1 1.7.34(0.285/5/3) 2015-02-04 12:12 i686 unknown unknown Cygwin
>
> g++ test1.cpp
>   // No errors, no warnings
>
> ./a.exe

l1 = 4294967296

l2 = 72057594037927934

**l3 = 4294967294**

d1 = 4294967296

d2 = 72057594037927934

**d3 = 0           // Expected 4294967294**

```
// -------- Program test1. cpp --------
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{

  long long l1 = 4294967296;
  long long l2 = 72057594037927934;
  long long l3 = l2 % l1;

  long double d1 = static_cast<long double>(l1);
  long double d2 = static_cast<long double>(l2);
  long double d3 = fmod (d2, d1);

  std::cout << "l1 = " << l1 << std::endl;
  std::cout << "l2 = " << l2 << std::endl;
  std::cout << "l3 = " << l3 << std::endl;

  std::cout << std::endl;
  std::cout << "d1 = " << std::setprecision(18) << d1 << std::endl;
  std::cout << "d2 = " << std::setprecision(18) << d2 << std::endl;
  std::cout << "d3 = " << std::setprecision(18) << d3 << std::endl;

  return 0;

}
// -----------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Floating point types, including `long double` cannot represent all integral values in their range.    In practice, they are less likely to support larger magnitude values precisely.

A consequence is that converting large integral values to `long double` (or any floating point type) does not necessarily preserve value - the converted value is only the closest approximation possible given limits of the floating point type.

From there, if your two conversions have produced different values, it would be very lucky if the result of `fmod()` was exactly the value you seek.

`fmod()` is also not overloaded to accept `long double` arguments.  Which means your `long double` values will be converted to `double`.   The set of values a `double` can represent is a subset of the set that a `long double` can represent.  Among other things, that means a smaller range of integral values that can be represented exactly.

The usual suggestion is not to do such things.   If you can do required operations using integer operations (like `%`) then do so.   And, if you use floating point, you need to allow for and manage the loss of precision associated with using floating point.

Comment: d2 contains 17 decimal digits. std::numeric_limits<long double>::digits10 == 18. So, it seems that d3 should be valid value.

Comment: Ah, okay.  There is also the fact that `fmod()` only accepts arguments of type `double`, and returns a `double`.   I'll add a note about that shortly.

Comment: FWIW, fmodl() takes long doubles and gives a much more accurate answer, d4 = fmodl(d2, d1) is 4294967294. Tested with g++ 4.8.4 on Ubuntu 14.04, on an x86_64 machine.

Comment: `fmodl()` is C99 and not in any C++ standard, IIRC.   But, yes, some C++ compilers/libraries support it as an extension.